# MongoDB installation error: "mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so.1..."

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I use this tutorial to install mongodb on my 64 bit Ubuntu OS:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

After finish the installation i enter:

```
mongo
```

Since then, an error message appear:

```
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Do you have any idea to solve this problem ? Here is my system information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
OS Type: 64 bit.
MongoDB version: mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1410-clang-3.0.6.
```

Comment: Have You tried [official tutorial for installing MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) ? The biggest difference --- adding Mongo repository and installing binaries from there. This way dependencies are going to be taken care by `apt` itself.

Comment: It looks like you downloaded wrong version of mongo. Try another one without clang suffix: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.6.tgz

Answer (score 9):

I use Ubuntu 14.04.3 64-bits (mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1410-clang-3.2.4), I was able to install libc++.so.1 related packages using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc++1
```

**Note**:
My Ubuntu VM using corporate proxy, initially 'sudo apt-get install libc++1' gave an error. Since I have Synaptic Package Manager installed, I tried Synaptic to install libc++1 and it was successful. MongoDB started and worked. To double check whether the mentioned command works, I did

```
sudo apt-get remove libc++1
sudo apt-get install libc++1
```

and the commands worked.
In case you need to using Synaptic as well, here is the screen shot
[image: ubuntu-install-libc++1]

Answer (score 1):

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

MongoDB: 3.2.6

Requires to execute below commands in order to work with mongod

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install libc++1**

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1410-clang-3.2.1) after installing this package libc++1 (LLVM C++ Standard library) problem was solved.